# How to get topics list from Kafka using C#

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka

I want to get topics list from Kafka. I'm using kafka-net client but unable to find in documentation about fetching topics list.

Comment: See this if it helps : http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201303.mbox/%3CCAF8-MNdWhmuUuaF8YAnie8PNRBRecxdW+vZ1pKrov5ftboQBMA@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: There is an answer here using java : [Get topics list frm kafka][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902301/how-to-get-topic-list-from-kafka-server-in-java

Comment: From the code, it does not seem that *kafka-net* provides it. It you need it, you may open an issue on Github.

Answer (score 13):

You can list all topics using the AdminClient available in Confluent.Kafka package:

```
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Confluent.Kafka.Admin;

var adminConfig = new AdminClientConfig()
{
   BootstrapServers = "SERVER_URL"
};

using (var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(adminConfig).Build())
{
   var metadata = adminClient.GetMetadata(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   var topicsMetadata = metadata.Topics;
   var topicNames = metadata.Topics.Select(a => a.Topic).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation you should be able to do this with

```
producer.GetMetadata(true, null)
```

> `public Metadata GetMetadata(bool allTopics, string topic)`
>
> Query the cluster for metadata (blocking).
>
> allTopics = true - request all topics from cluster

https://docs.confluent.io/4.0.1/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.Producer.html#Confluent_Kafka_Producer_GetMetadata_System_Boolean_System_String_

Comment: There no Producer class in dotnet core supporitng nuget , and also existing Iproducer deosnt have this GetMetadata() method.