# Command to list all the topics from Kafka Version 0.8.1

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am looking to list all the topics from kafka

Seems like in 0.8 version there was kafka-list-topics.sh ([How to get topic list from kafka server in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902301/how-to-get-topic-list-from-kafka-server-in-java))

However I am not able to find the same in 0.8.1. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.1/bin

Any pointer would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I got it

in 0.8 it was

**./kafka-list-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:9200**

in 0.8.1+ it is

**./kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:9200**